# Implemented Tensorflow Op Kernel not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to implement an fft op kernel for CPU. Since eigen got an fft implementation this shouldn't be too hard, but I am always running in an `InvalidArgumentError` when trying to use it from python (see below). I don't understand why it isn't found, the kernel is implemented and registered.

Code of kernel for fft op on CPU (modification of [this file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/fft_ops.cc)):

```
...
// CPU Implementation
template <bool Forward>
class FFTCPU1D : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit FFTCPU1D(OpKernelConstruction* ctx) : OpKernel(ctx) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* ctx) override {
    const Tensor& in = ctx->input(0);
    const TensorShape& shape = in.shape();
    OP_REQUIRES(ctx, shape.dims() != 1,
      errors::InvalidArgument("Input must have rank 1, but got: ",
                                shape.DebugString()));

    Tensor* out;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(ctx, ctx->allocate_output(0, shape, &out));
    if (Forward) {
        out.vec<std::complex<Scalar>>() = kernel_variant.template fft<Eigen::BothParts, FFT_FORWARD>(fft).vec()<std::complex<Scalar>>;
    } else {
        out.vec<std::complex<Scalar>>() = kernel_variant.template fft<Eigen::BothParts, FFT_REVERSE>(fft).vec()<std::complex<Scalar>>;
    }
  }

};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("FFT").Device(DEVICE_CPU), FFTCPU1D<true>);
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("IFFT").Device(DEVICE_CPU), FFTCPU1D<false>);
...
```

Python-Script for testing:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
data = np.complex64(np.random.normal(size=1024))
input = tf.constant(data)
print(input.dtype)
fftOp = tf.fft(input)

print(sess.run(fftOp))
```

Error-Message:

```
# python ~/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(sess.run(fftOp))
  File "/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 332, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 572, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 652, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 672, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'FFT' with these attrs
         [[Node: FFT = FFT[](Const)]]
Caused by op u'FFT', defined at:
  File "/root/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    fftOp = tf.fft(input)
  File "/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 518, in fft
    return _op_def_lib.apply_op("FFT", input=input, name=name)
  File "/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 693, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2177, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1161, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

I've got the gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel docker image and built tensorflow according to the [instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#setting_up_tensorflow_for_development).

Comment: You have a better chance of getting this answered if you open a GitHub issue with the TensorFlow project. Please make sure you provide detailed repro instructions.